# Heroku is not accepting python-3.9.9 even though it is supported

Tags: python, heroku

I am trying to upload my website to Heroku and I can't get past the (git push heroku master) part. I am following the steps in "Python crash course". I have my python version in my runtime.txt but I keep getting the error

```
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Requested runtime () is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
```

My `runtime.txt` has `python-3.9.9` in it.

I know python-3.9.9 is supported based on devcenter

Picture of devcenter supported runtimes:

[image]

Picture of my runtime code:

[image]

My runtime is in the root directory.

Picture of the error I am getting:

[image]

I cant push my website because of this and I can't figure it out. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `runtime.txt` does not contain what you think it does. The error says

> Requested runtime () is not available for this stack (heroku-20)

The value in those parentheses shows what Heroku sees in your `runtime.txt`: it's seeing an empty string, not `python-3.9.9`.

The `runtime.txt` you show in your screenshot is modified (see the "⬤" in the tab). Save it, commit it, then deploy  again.

Comment: That worked, thank you!